# Handling mouse click event when a window opens in MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm-light

When a WPF window opens it must be ready to handle a mouse click event.
It must handle this event until the window is closed.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: click on any window's control or window itself?

Answer (score 0):

you can create a single function with the shared behavior in your window, then call that function from both your loaded handler and your button click handler.

like-

```
 void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        button1_Click(sender, new RoutedEventArgs());
     }
```